# Паттерн singleton

Tags: ооп, php

Покажите на пальцах для чего нужен **Singleton**?

```
class Singleton {

    protected static $instance;  // object instance

    /**
     * Защищаем от создания через new Singleton
     *
     * @return Singleton
     */
    private function __construct() { /* ... */ }

    /**
     * Защищаем от создания через клонирование
     *
     * @return Singleton
     */
    private function __clone() { /* ... */ }

    /**
     * Защищаем от создания через unserialize
     *
     * @return Singleton
     */
    private function __wakeup() { /* ... */ }

    /**
     * Возвращает единственный экземпляр класса
     *
     * @return Singleton
     */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if ( is_null(self::$instance) ) {
            self::$instance = new Singleton;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function doAction() { /* ... */ }

}

//usage
Singleton::getInstance()->doAction();
```

**Для чего писать так? Если можно написать вот так:**

```
class Singleton {
    public static function doAction() { /* ... */ }
}

Singleton::doAction();
```

**Не проще, нет? %)**

Только не нужно давать ссылок на википедию и т.п.

---

**Всем спасибо!** [[@knes](/users/2825/knes)](/users/2825/knes), [[@ikoolik](/users/5777/ikoolik)](/users/5777/ikoolik) и [[@Nord001](/users/6627/nord001)](/users/6627/nord001) — накинул вам по 25 очков за старание.

Comment: натолкнулся на предысторию этого вопроса.

@AlexWindHope, ждем Вас с нетерпением.

Comment: @ikoolik, да-да, ждем.

Comment: @knes уже и так все замечательно расписал, разницу между наличием экземпляра и полным его отсутствием, на пальцах, расписал @ikoolik в комментариях к своему ответу. Чего вам еще нужно?

Я уже писал, если и после этого не понятно - значит не доросли, сама суть прекрасно описана в википедии +, теперь, разжована здесь.

Comment: а что, статьи не будет? =(

Comment: Представьте себе =)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Синглтон нужен, чтобы точно знать, что у нас создан ОДИН объект данного класса. Классический пример - коннект к базе данных.

Если куча скриптов внутри одного файла теребит БД в разных функциях, приходится заводить глобальную переменную соединения и постоянно проверять жива ли она, на случай если в данный момент идет первое подключение к БД.

Синглтон же сам создает соединение, если оно еще не было установлено, либо просто возвращает готовую ссылку. Вам же требуется только вызвать его, уже ни о чем не заботясь: лишний раз базу не потревожат.

Второй ваш пример плох тем, что можно насоздавать кучу объектов данного класса, которые не будут знать что происходит у остальных.

Comment: Короче примерно понял. Это если используется функция `__construct()`, то при каждом вызове `db::select()` будет вызываться `__construct()`?

Comment: Нет. Конструктор в синглтоне вызывается один раз на все время жизни скрипта.

Comment: Не понял во общем.

Comment: @exec, конструктор синглтона приватный, то есть объект нельзя создать снаружи. А при вызове функции getInstance проверяется существует ли уже экземпляр, если нет - создается. Отсюда получается, что только один экземпляр объекта может в принципе существовать.
Хотя Вы просили без ссылок, но лучше почитать хороших авторов: Майерса, Александреску. Или хотя бы [хабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/116577/)

Comment: @northerner, если у меня полностью статичный класс, я не создаю его экземпляр, а использую вот так `core::error()` в косяк такого использования?

Comment: Это не косяк использования синглтона. Это просто использование класса в качестве пространства имен.

Comment: Если в Вашем классе только статические функции, то профит введения синглетона сомнителен. Более того перекрывается [недостатками](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/design/2615563.flat.aspx#2615563).

Другое дело, если есть поля данных.

Comment: @knes - солидарен, про шаблон, в вики, написано здорово

Comment: Плохой пример ИМХО . В реальных порталах - бывает куча соединений к разным БД. Да и в общем то синглтон действительно тоже самое что статик - единственное, плохо получается если вдруг начинающий прогер начинает статик-класс инстанцировать, и пихать туда не-статик свойства/методы: но так могут только бегиннеры делать. А если пару статик методов появятся в синглтоне руками того-же бегиннера - ничего страшного не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Синглтон - один из самых легких, но в то же время предельно значимых паттернов проектирования. Для чего он нужен, уже был дан ответ. Основная реализация показана вами, а вот плюшки каждый может привинтить свои. Так, например, в C++ можно создать отдельный шаблонный класс Singleton методом `template<type>`, а далее уже делать из любого существующего класса синглтон.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что синглтон позволяет создать только один свой экземпляр.

Соответственно все классы, в которых используется объект синглтона, используют один и тот же объект. С одними и теми же данными.

Возьмем пример из ответа товарища [[@knes](/users/2825/knes)](/users/2825/knes) про соединение с БД. Если соединение с БД занесено в конструктор синглтона, то все классы использующие БД через синглтон используют одно и то же соединение.

Еще пример:

```
***
тут обьявление обычного класса `MyClass` с `private $a` и `getA(), setA()`
***        
$class1 = new MyClass();
$class2 = new MyClass();
$class2->setA(3);
$class1->setA(5);
echo $class2->getA(); //3
```

То же, если myClass - синглтон:

```
$class1 = myClass::getInstance();
$class2 = myClass::getInstance();
$class2->setA(3);
$class1->setA(5);
echo $class2->getA(); //5
```

Все вышеизложенное - лишь наиболее понятная на мой взгляд иллюстрация механизма. Преимущества и недостатки синглтона - другая история.

Comment: > Еще пример: Добавим в синглтон произвольную переменную. Затем добавим для нее geter и seter. Все просто. Фишка в том, что мы можем указать значение этой переменной в одном классе, а получить в другом БЕЗ передачи объекта синглтона между классами.

У меня и без синглтона это работает.

Answer (score 1):

Выше писали про БД, я так ипользую:

> Singleton::getInstance('main')->doAction();
>
> Singleton::getInstance('no_main')->doAction();

Поясню. Есть 3 сайта. 4 БД. Из них 3 БД - это БД с инфой конкретного сайта, а четвёртая БД это данные пользователей, т.к. на всех 3х сайтах они одинаковы. Поэтому когда мне надо сделать запрос к БД пользователей я использую:

> Singleton::getInstance('main')->doAction();

если допустим нужны статьи, то:

> Singleton::getInstance('no_main')->doAction();

Тем самым у меня гарантированно будет не более 1 подключения к конкретной БД.

По сути можно делать как вы и написали:

> Singleton::doAction();

Но если вам нужно будет какие-нибудь данные, то вы всё равно будете вызывать >getInstance()
для того что бы обратиться допустим к БД.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Singleton {
private static $PrS='init private';
public static  $PuS='init public';
    public static function PrS($A=false) { 
      if($A!==false)   
          self::$PrS=$A;
      else
          return self::$PrS;
    }
    public static function PuS($A=false) { 
      if($A!==false)   
          self::$PuS=$A;
      else
          return self::$PuS;
   }
}

echo Singleton::PrS();
echo "\n";
echo Singleton::PuS(); // выведет init private
                       //         init public
echo "\n -- \n";

$D = new Singleton();
echo $D->PrS(); // также выведет init private
echo "\n";      //               init public
echo $D->PuS();
echo "\n -- \n SET them all!";     // А вот здесь 
Singleton::PrS('changed private'); // меняем переменные класса
Singleton::PuS('changed public');  //  используя статическую ссылку
echo "\n";      // и попробуем проверить их из "созданного" класса (хотя это просто ссылка копия)
echo $D->PrS(); // разумеется, выведет: changed private 
echo "\n";      
echo $D->PuS(); //                      changed public
```

скопируйте этот простой пример, запустите его, и вам будет понятно, что статический класс, вместе с его статическими же переменными не дублируется оператором new.
Да хоть десять дублей наделайте - все равно - статические переменные останутся.

Слово static для функции говорит о том, что в глобальной таблице при компиляции ей уже выделен адрес - жестко выделен. Так же и со статическими переменными - их адрес также статичен.
А НЕстатические переменные (классы) не существуют в адресном пространстве, пока их не определят (оператором new). Обращаться некуда. Для статических адрес уже есть - и к нему (к переменной) можно обратиться всегда - someStaticClass::value

Хотите использовать статический класс для работы с БД  - заведите внутри приватную статическую переменную DB_handler. Надо работать с несколькими соединениями (несколько БД) - заведите еще по необходимости. Можно даже соорудить нечто статического массива.
Почему нет? Появится необходимость слишком извернуться - перепишите класс.
Т.е. копии статических классов вообще не различаются (при изготовлении их оператором new), пока в них не появится хотя бы одна НЕстатическая переменная. Правда, и после этого различаться они будут только этой НЕстатической переменной. Правда, при этом, управлять этой переменной уже получится уже только из изготовленного класса.

Далее:

```
public static function getInstance() {
        if ( is_null(self::$instance) ) {
            self::$instance = new Singleton;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
```

Вот этот кусок кода как раз и возвращает копию ссылки на адрес статического класса Singleton. Это то же самое, что написать Singleton::(и там что-то)

Вот об этом и был вопрос - "ЗАЧЕМ?". Ответ простой - да, НЕЗАЧЕМ :)

Наверное, есть задачи, где надо заводить экземпляр класса Singleton, "*...а вот если не было обращений (ну не потребовалось что-то), то ничего не заведется и все будет тихо и спокойно... А вот вроде как статический класс будет существовать даже тогда, когда он может не понадобиться... и ух, как страшно съест памяти...*" В общем, как-то я не могу вот так с ходу придумать такой задачи, чтобы применять именно СОЗДАНИЕ классов вместо статических классов.

И вот я например, тоже не вижу разницы между сложным Singleton наворотом и простым Singleton::doAction(). 
Вообще, статические классы (со статическими переменными) чрезвыйчано удобны еще и тем, что они предоставляют как бы "глобальные" переменные для любой области видимости. И хэндлер для БД тому яркий пример.

Comment: Ага, только не асилил - если так удобны статические методы, зачем тогда вообще юзать ООП? Для пространств имен? Так они в PHP и так есть.

Вы просто, как и ТС, не совсем понимаете зачем нужно ООП

Comment: Это то же самое, что написать Singleton::(и там что-то)

Да ну?..

Если бы было незачем - его бы не использовали, более того - его бы не существовало, то что вы не понимаете сути проблема исключтельно ваша, никак не патерна

Comment: Во общем мне это не нужно. У меня всё классы статические и переменные в них тоже.

Comment: Тогда вам вообще **нафиг** не нужно ООП

Comment: Ну что же, ещё одним человеком, которому "нафиг не нужно ООП" больше. В этом смысле хорош питон -- не нужна его объектность -- ну и не надо на ней заморачиваться.

Comment: пока толкового комментария не прочел, одни возгласы :))

Comment: Если вы толком не знаете что такое ООП, вы естественно не поймете зачем нужны ООП патерны. Достаточно толково написал?

Comment: посмотрите внимательно:
self::$instance = new Singleton;
что вам возвратит? Он ссылку возвратит. Статическую. Она уже есть. И меняться не будет. Хоть десять раз new сделайте... :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope Холивар? ООП паттерны -- средство для борьбы с недостатками ООП и контретных языков ООП. Вроде так. Применять с осторожностью, иначе (применение трёх-четырёх шаблонов одновременно) программа автоматически становится нечитабельной.

Comment: @Cooleronline, по Вашей логике получается, что ООП тоже не нужно, потому что всё можно переписать процедурно.

Получив ссылку на экземпляр синглетона, Вы можете передавать ее параметром других методов, строить интерфейсы. Это в корне отличает синглетон от "pure static" класса.

Также неплохой анализ найдете [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/103681/).