# Автозагрузка php-классов

Tags: php, ооп, composer

Переписываю движок с процедурного метода на ООП. Создаю несколько классов в начале каждого пишу

```
namespace ...
use ...
```

Мне выпадают ошибки `class not found`. Подскажите, как организовать автозагрузку классов, например, с помощью Composer. Можно ли автоматически сформировать `composer.json` по своему проекту?

До этого использовал его только для подключения сторонних библиотек.

Answer (score 1):

При подключении composer к своему проекту вместо

```
require "../vendor/autoload.php";
```

пишите

```
$loader = require "../vendor/autoload.php";
$loader->setPsr4('ВАШ_NameSpace\\', 'ПУТЬ_ДО_КОРНЯ_ВАШЕГО_NameSpace');
```

После этого composer подхватывает и ваши классы.

Comment: А зачем? Можно ведь это в самом `composer.json` указать.

Comment: @Visman, вроде немного разобрался. сделал подключение файла настроек, в нем устанавливаются константы (они передаются все нормально), а вот если задать какую-нибудь переменную, то к ней почему то нельзя обратится из другого файла. не подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: @Дмитрий, при ООП не должно быть глобальных переменных. Переменные нужно передавать явно, например, при создании экземпляра класса или вызове метода. Или сохранять их в хранилище, которое доступно из любого класса. В качестве хранилища можно использовать Singleton http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/92217/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd-singleton

Comment: @Visman, я не рассчитывал что переменная будет глобальной,  просто прикинул что composer autoload делает абсолютно то же самое как если бы я просто require_once файл с настройками. Соответственно, припилил бы мне кусок кода из другого файла. оказалось, что это не совсем так, и константы стали глобальными, а вот переменная осталась жить внутри конфига. По поводу синглтона, не уверен, что он реализован в самом Smarty. А значит лепить класс, который будет следить за этим. Хотя может кто по другому использует шаблонизаторы?

Comment: @Дмитрий, со Smarty не работал, но судя по документации http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/api.assign.tpl нужно использовать метод assign() для передачи переменных в шаблон. Передать вы можете не только простую переменную, но и массив, и объект.

Comment: @Visman, да в этом то все и дело, в конфигах я передаю объекту настройки. и поэтому, мне нужен только один экземпляр в приложении.

Answer (score 1):

Если используете Composer, то и настройки подключаемых файлов или папок пишите в `composer.json`.

Официальная документация:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

Есть на русском языке небольшая статья на эту тему:

- https://habrahabr.ru/post/149678/