# MySQL: Too many connections

Tags: php, mysql, linux, bash, shell

Здравствуйте.

Почти ежечасно, я  стал получать ошибку у себя на сайте при подключении к MySQL:

`PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections in /var/www/http/inc/classes/db.class.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /var/www/http/inc/classes/db.class.php on line 99`

При выполнении SQL-запроса `show status like '%conn%'` выводит число 4971052, и со временем число этих подключений увеличивается. У меня есть NodeJS скрипт, который вызывает php скрипт из консоли, а в php скрипте осуществляются запросы к базе, а после скрипт завершает свою работу, но подключения почему-то остаются. Такой скрипт запускается 400-500 раз каждые 5 секунд.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы количество подключений не росло, а держалось в районе 1000 подключений (максимум)?

Comment: закрывать их в конце работы скрипта мб?

Comment: @teran а как, не подскажете? я использую в функции __destruct, класса базы данных, mysql_close, но это не помогает

Comment: У меня была такая проблема. Решилась тем что на innoDB перевели все таблицы

Comment: @ikerya а как ты к ***MySQL*** коннектишься?. Может следует почитать про паттерн Singeltone

Comment: @dpi подключаюсь вот так: http://prntscr.com/h2rotq

Comment: Если используется mysqli - то не нужно ничего закрывать - соединение само закрывается при завершении работы php-скрипта. Прекратите вводить людей в заблуждение.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский а как тогда быть? скрипт завершает свою работу, но соединение продолжает висеть

Comment: @ikerya, сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/92217/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd-singleton загляните.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский а для чего `mysqli.allow_persistent` существует?

Comment: @ikerya, всё очень просто. Вы пишете "Такой скрипт запускается 400-500 раз каждые 5 секунд" - просто прекратите так делать. Внезапный спойлер: красота ООП + постепенная подгрузка всех кусочков страницы аяксом **мешают** оптимальности скриптов и логики.

Comment: @teran, интересная штука, не знал, спасибо) А для чего именно такое используют обычно? Посоветуете что почитать?

Comment: @АлександрБелинский как обычно, сначала [мануал](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php). а вообще хз что читать, мало работаю с mysql и mysqli, а nodejs в глаза не видел:D

Comment: @АлександрБелинский вы о чем? как это перестать? причем аякс, если скрипт работает из консоли?

Comment: @ikerya, тем более. Скрипт в студию, плз.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский http://prntscr.com/h2rygg

Comment: @ikerya, ага, славно. и для чего он нужен? и сразу еще - для чего его нужно запускать 500 раз каждые 5 секунд?

Comment: @АлександрБелинский вы помогаете проблему решать или хотите поговорить для чего скрипт нужен?

Comment: @ikerya, решение при поставленной формулировке я уже описал - прекратите вызывать скрипт каждые 5 секунд по 500 раз. А для того чтобы подсказать **как** это сделать - нужно уже понимать, что именно "автор хотел сказать этим скриптом", или как-то так. Безусловно, наверняка есть тысячи способов временно решить Вашу проблему, поковыряв немного настройки сервера или докупив мощностей машине. Но это временные решения, моя религия не позволяет мне к ним прибегать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не правельно смотрите подключения) Это статистика, сколько всего было коннектов =))

```
show variables like 'max_connections';
```

Так можно увидеть сколько максимально единомоментно может быть подключений.
По умолчанию там помоему 100. И так как у вас 500 скриптов в 5 секунд, то возможно ситуация когда единомоментно может быть больше 100 подключений и вы ловите ошибку.

Максимальное количество подключений можно увеличить в конфиге мускуля, но стоит помнить что каждое подключение кушает память и mysql может вылететь за её пределы.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ, очень помогли :)